# Go back to previous line in python?

Tags: python

Im trying to create the following such that it reassigns the variable as I go.

```
def train(old_strength, old_energy): 
    train = input("What would you like to do now?\n'strentgh' or 'rest'\n>")

    if train == 'strength':
        strength = old_strength+10
        energy = old_energy-10


        if energy <= 0:
            print ("You do not have enough energy to do this.")

        else:   
            pass

        print ("You have gained 10 strength, and now have %d strength and %d energy left" %(strength, energy))
        old_strength = strength)
        old_energy = energy)        
        train(old_strength, old_energy)
```

Im trying to get it so that when it goes back to the 'train' input, it will then use the new strength and energy values for the next time.
At the moment I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "settler.py", line 127, in <modul
    train(10, 50)
  File "settler.py", line 37, in train
    train(old_strength, old_energy)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How do I fix this?
Many Thanks in advance

Comment: What are these ")" at the end of `old_strength`/`old_energy` lines? And you've got a typo in second line with _strentgh_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reasigned `def train(....)` with `str` by writing `train = input(...)`.

That's why you get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

Use other variable for capturing `input`.

**EDIT:**

And in your second `if` statement (`energy <= 0`) maybe it's worth to do something more than just print notification? Like `return` ? or at leas include last 4 lines into the `else` block. But it's just a free thought, maybe you're just getting started with this.